# Off-topic for lack of research?

Tags: discussion, flagging

Why cannot questions on the main site be flagged as off-topic due to lack of research? The option is not there.

Comment: Lack of research is generally seen as a reason to downvote, not close.

Comment: @Hamlet Are ELL and ELU atypical in this respect?

Comment: it's possible for sites to add "custom close reasons", which is what I guess ELL and ELU did. This is something we could do after we leave private beta. But my sense is that the majority of the userbase would be opposed to a custom close reason for lack of research.

Comment: @Mick Yes, definitely. A custom close reason which essentially comes down to "bad question" has been implemented on a few sites such as ELU and M&TV, after much community discussion, but on most sites "bad question" is a reason to downvote, not to VTC. Like all private betas, this site currently has no custom close reasons.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Thanks. That explains why a lot of questions on Stack Overflow get hammered.

Answer (score 7):

**Because that's not what makes them off-topic, that's why you *downvote***.

The downvote button, on mouseover, says:

> This question does **not show any research effort;** it is unclear or not useful

Remember, a VTC [is not a super-downvote](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/is-the-distinction-too-subtle-between-downvoting-and-voting-to-close/5479#5479).

And the Help Center on voting says:

> Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while **voting down** a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is **poorly researched**, or fails to communicate information.